# Is Prism still being actively developed?

Tags: wpf, prism

I've been to the codeplex site and I see members and a few bug reports, but I can't tell if there is new development going on or if it is just in cruise mode.  Anyone have any further details?

*Edit for comments*
Many issues are proposed [Proposed Issues](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic)

but the last time a code commit occurred was in November, 2010

[Code Commit](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, commits don't occur unless there is some sort of hotfix, or a release.  The codeplex repository isn't used for incremental updates such a nightlies or similar releases, more big bang.

Look forward to more information about the PRISM roadmap after BUILD in September.
http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/discussions/261609

Comment: Here's an update that includes the Prism 4.5 roadmap, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/practices/bb232643